# htmlunit driver gives me com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.InteractivePage error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Please find my code snippet here and I am using `rhel` box in linux:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/ap/register?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dnav_newcust");
driver.findElement(By.id("ap_customer_name")).sendKeys("krish"); // line 24
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.InteractivePage
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$HtmlUnitTargetLocator.activeElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1332)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.switchFocusToThisIfNeeded(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:292)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.sendKeys(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:330)
    at com.amazon.digitalmusic.UnitBrowser.main(UnitBrowser.java:24)
```

HTMLunit-2.17 and selenium jar files are there in my project path.

I tried googling but could not be able to resolve it. Could some help in this and where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a version incompatibility between HtmlUnit and WebDriver.

`com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.InteractivePage` was introduced into HtmlUnit on 26 July 2015, as the new base class for `HtmlPage`, which [corresponds to release 2.18](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a2.18).

However, WebDriver has been [checking for `InteractivePage`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.48.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.java#L1332) since release 2.48.0, which you must have. So anyone mixing up WebDriver >= 2.48 with HtmlUnit < 2.18 is going to get that error.

The solution is to update your HtmlUnit (**2.20** is the latest) - or if you use Maven etc., remove the dependency altogether, as the correct version should/will be included by WebDriver itself.